# Sorting elasticsearch Range Aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

Is it possible to change the sorting of results of a Range Aggregation in elasticsearch? I have a keyed Range query in elasticsearch and want to sort according to keys instead of doc_count.

**My documents are:**

```
POST /docs/doc/1
{
    "price": 12
}

POST /docs/doc/2
{
    "price": 8
}

POST /docs/doc/3
{
    "price": 15
}
```

**And the aggregation query:**

```
POST /docs/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "price_ranges": {
         "range": {
            "field": "price",
            "keyed": true,
            "ranges": [
               {
                  "key": "all",
                  "from": 0
               },
               {
                  "key": "to10",
                  "from": 0,
                  "to": 10
               },
               {
                  "key": "from11",
                  "from": 11
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**The result for this query is:**

```
"aggregations": {
   "price_ranges": {
      "buckets": {
         "to10": {
            "from": 0,
            "from_as_string": "0.0",
            "to": 10,
            "to_as_string": "10.0",
            "doc_count": 2
         },
         "all": {
            "from": 0,
            "from_as_string": "0.0",
            "doc_count": 4
         },
         "from11": {
            "from": 11,
            "from_as_string": "11.0",
            "doc_count": 2
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I'd like to sort the results according to the key, not according to range value. According to elasticsearch documentation it is not possible to specify a sort order and When specifying a sort order I get the following exception:

```
"reason": "Unknown key for a START_ARRAY in [price_ranges]: [order]."
```

Any ideas on how to cope with this? Thanks!

Comment: The issue is that when keyed is true, the result is returned as a hash which is unordered by definition, to the contrary of an array which is ordered. Have you tried to configure `"all"` with `"from": -1`, maybe it'll come up first?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to do this for range aggregations.  I think the best way to cope with this is to sort the buckets in the client.

Answer (score 2):

Since the keys seem to be ordered according to ascending values of the `from` value, you can "cheat" a little bit and modify the `from` value of the `all` bucket to -1, then the `all` bucket will appear first, then `to10` and finally `from11`:

```
POST /docs/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "aggs": {
      "price_ranges": {
         "range": {
            "field": "price",
            "keyed": true,
            "ranges": [
               {
                  "key": "all",
                  "from": -1
               },
               {
                  "key": "to10",
                  "from": 0,
                  "to": 10
               },
               {
                  "key": "from11",
                  "from": 11
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a nice workaround for the missing ordering in range aggregations. Do you know the technical reasons why the ordering is missing?

Comment: Good question, but I guess since a hash (i.e. map) is unordered by definition they didn't really want to change that semantics. When accessing your buckets, you won't be able to get them in order anyway, you'll have to access them by name (i.e. whatever their order)

Answer (score 1):

In general you can use a [bucket_sort aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-sort-aggregation.html). Then you can sort by `_key`, `_count` or a sub-aggregation (i.e. by a metric calculated for each bucket).

Given that you only have three fixed buckets though, I would simply do the sorting on the client-side instead.